# the render order of an array of React components is wrong

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of react components I'm trying to render in a specific order. Something like this:

```js
render: function() {
  var items = stock.map(function(item) {
    return <NewLI data={item} key={item.id}/>
  }
  return <ul>{items}</ul>
}
```

My problem is that React is not returning the `li`'s in the order of the original array (the actual component is more complex than a single `li`, but it is properly wrapped in a `div`).

so if print the `id` keys of items, I get this:

```js
items.forEach(function(a) { console.log(a.id) })
```

returns

```
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
```

but my React render looks like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li...>2</li>
  <li...>3</li>
  <li...>4</li>
  <li...>1</li>
</ul>
```

Is this expected behaviour? Is there a way to guarantee the order?

Comment: What does the `stock` array look like? Also, it would be great if you can provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Something is wierd in your `stock` array...the ids must not be corresponding the content of the `li` like you expect.  can we see that array please

Answer (score 0):

You can define a sorted array before mapping and rendering it.

```
render: function() {
  stock.sort(comparefunction)
  var items = stock.map(function(item) {
    return <NewLI data={item} key={item.id}/>
  }
  return <ul>{items}</ul>
}

comparefunction = (s1,s2) => {
   if(s1.propToSortBy > s2.propToSortBy)   //assuming each element is an object
       return 1;
   if(s1.propToSortBy > s2.propToSortBy) 
       return -1;
   
    return 0;
}
```

Please add details to how the `stock` array looks like so we can have a better understanding.

Comment: But according to the second code sample in the question, the `items` array is already sorted correctly.

Comment: But why doing sorting when the array is already sorted